# Foreach type mismatch MVC 4

Tags: foreach, asp.net-mvc-4, type-mismatch

My question is related to a beginner's topic (sorry for that...). I'm just starting with MVC and at this moment i'm trying to understand the concepts and strucute

I came from webform way of doing things and now i need to simulate the old webform repeater into MVC. Looking for an alternative on the web i discovered that foreach loops are one of the MVC's way of achieving this, correct ?

Then i bit of context (and please, correct me if something i say indicates a wrong understanding of some concept)...

This is my model class created via edmx file

```
    public partial class qryMonitor
{
    public int Nsu { get; set; }
    public string NomeDaSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public string Grupo { get; set; }
    public string Prioridade { get; set; }
    public string Transito { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdDestinatario { get; set; }
    public string NomeAutor { get; set; }
    public string DepartamentoAutor { get; set; }
    public int IdAutor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdAnalistaDesignado { get; set; }
    public string NomeAnalistaDesignado { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdSuperiorAnalistaDesignado { get; set; }
    public string NomeSuperiorAnalistaDesignado { get; set; }
    public string Atividade { get; set; }
    public string CodigoRgb1 { get; set; }
    public string DataSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public int MarcarSolicitacao { get; set; }
}
```

Then i created another class with a single property...

```
public class ChamadosViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<qryMonitor> Chamados { get; set; }
}
```

Now my controller's code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    EntidadesHelpDesk _dbHelpDesk = new EntidadesHelpDesk();
    ChamadosViewModel viewModel = new ChamadosViewModel()
    {
        Chamados = _dbHelpDesk.qryMonitor
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => x.Transito == "Respondida")
            .Select(x => new qryMonitor
            {
                Nsu = x.Nsu,
                Transito = x.Transito,
                NomeDaSolicitacao = x.NomeDaSolicitacao,
                NomeAutor = x.NomeAutor,
                Prioridade = x.Prioridade,
                DataSolicitacao = x.DataSolicitacao
            })
    };
        return View(viewModel);
}
```

and finally the view, created via wizard

```
@model IEnumerable<ServiceDesk.ViewModel.ChamadosViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })     |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey     */ }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey     */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

When i ran those, i get a type mismatch  (wich i'm able to comprehend, but not to solve). The complete massage is

```
"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type'ServiceDesk.ViewModel.ChamadosViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ServiceDesk.ViewModel.ChamadosViewModel]'."
```

I looked for some similar topics on the web... i found few, but i was not able to solve the problem by comparing the examples and the above situation.

One thing i noted is that usually at samples, i saw code like 
    "Model.ForeachData"

and in my case intelisense gets nothing besides the model itself (looks like a group of a group of things and not just like a simple group).

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english (not my main language). Thanks againg for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you are passing to your view contains a collection, but you are attempting to iterate directly over the model.

Change your view code to use the `Chamados` property.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Chamados)
```

Then, change your model type in your view:

```
@model ServiceDesk.ViewModel.ChamadosViewModel
```

Comment: I tried that but the intelisense does not recognizes the Chamados property in the Model. Is it necessary to change something at the model type on the top of the page to achieve that ? Thanks tor the reply.

Comment: Thanks, it worked... the intelisense does not recognized the chamados property at the first time. I had to give it a first build and then the property started beeing in the intelisense. Thanks againg, realy fast reply, hope i could be also helping in a near future. See ya.

Answer (score 0):

You define the view's model as `IEnumerable<ServiceDesk.ViewModel.ChamadosViewModel>` but in the controller you're not providing a collection, you're providing a single view model.

```
ChamadosViewModel viewModel = new ChamadosViewModel()
{
    Chamados = _dbHelpDesk.qryMonitor
        .ToList()
        .Where(x => x.Transito == "Respondida")
        .Select(x => new qryMonitor
        {
            Nsu = x.Nsu,
            Transito = x.Transito,
            NomeDaSolicitacao = x.NomeDaSolicitacao,
            NomeAutor = x.NomeAutor,
            Prioridade = x.Prioridade,
            DataSolicitacao = x.DataSolicitacao
        })
};
return View(viewModel);
```

So you either need to change what the controller is giving your view, or change what your view is expecting to receive.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast return. Could you please provide code sample of the modifications you sugested ? I mean... you said im not providing a collection, but i understand that the Chamados property should be doing this role, no ? Sorry, i just could not see through the necessary code changes. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaius, well to be honest I'm not sure what you're doing. The comment says you're using `item.PrimaryKey`, but you didn't show any class that has a PrimaryKey property. So are you trying to loop through `Chamados`? In which case see devigital's answer.

Comment: Thanks Brandom. Yeah, i was trying to loop through Chamados records. I fallowed devigital's tip and it worked. Thanks for your help.